# SQL Server While Loop return results as they are found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a SQL script that I've written that helps me search through a DB schema to find if certain columns are used (i.e. not null, not zero length string, etc) and what their most popular values are.

I'd really like to be able to return results as they're found in the loop since it could take a while to complete the entire search. Is there a way to return results in such a way that on the VB.NET side it will see the results as they are found when it tries to do `SqlDataReader.Read`?

Because right now, I'm storing the results in a temp table and returning the temp table at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: Short of using CLR and creating a streaming result set, which sends the data as it receives records, I think the best way to do this is to create a global temp table (e.g., `##temp`) and have a secondary process that shows the values / records in the global temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not when it's a single SQL script, no - the caller will wait for the full result set before moving on.

However, you could break it into a few steps, like this:

- Make the initial lookup, where you list all the columns you might be interested in
- Return these results to VB.NET
- For each result in this set, run the rest of your process to get the values you're actually interested in. Loop through each result from the first step
- As you receive each collection of data, you can choose to do something with it if you want. Spin off a new thread, for example, to do some additional processing.

So if it's a single T-SQL script, you're stuck running it and returning the results at one time - but if you're able to break it up and execute the loop inside .NET instead of inside SQL, you'll have access to the results at each step.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks. After I retrieve the first result set (which is very quick) of the schema, as I'm looping through in .NET to check the usage for each of the columns, it's probably best to use one SQLConnection object, right? Disconnecting and reconnecting each time for each column to check its usage would probably be a major bottlneck, right?

Comment: It wouldn't be major, as the connection negotiation is pretty quick - however, there's no need to disconnect at all, so it would make sense to reuse the same connection for each step in the loop. As a point of habit, I usually wrap my data connection code in a "Using" statement where I define the SqlConnection, as that adds the close/disposal code for you in a Finally block at compile time.